# How to use tidy with vim without unix linebreak in quickfix window and how to correct only the errors?

Tags: vim, tidy

After a lot of searching and trying I found this to make my tidy work with vim:

```
:set makeprg=tidy\ -e\ --gnu-emacs\ yes 
:set shellpipe=2>
:set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:\ %m
:make %
:copen
```

But why does the output in the quickfix window has an `^M` unix line-break at the end of every line?
I tried to remove it but the content in quickfix window is not modifiable.

I tried also to make tidy correct the errors, but only the errors.

I created this:

```
   let errorf = "d:\\error.txt"
   let currentf = expand("%:p")
   let writef = "d:\\".expand("%:t:r")."_tidy.".expand("%:e")

   exe a:type."!tidy -w 0 -f ".errorf." -o ".writef." ".currentf 
   exe ":bot split ".writef
   exe ":bot split ".errorf
```

But this changes the complete output of my file.
I want to correct only the errors.
I have read the manual of tidy but can't find a simple option to correct only the errors without changing the rest of the file.
p.e.

```
<h1>test</h2>  --> <h1>test</h1>
```

Are there tidy users who know how to change only the errors in tidy?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of tidy to sed to create a filter to remove carriage returns before vim puts it in the quickfix window.

```
set makeprg=tidy\ -e\ --gnu-emacs\ yes\ $*\ \\\|\ sed\ 's/\\r$//'
```

The pipe needs to be escaped twice one by set and once for the interpretation of the command.

The sed command I used was

```
sed 's/\r$//
```

Which removes carriage returns that appear at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm in a windows environment and can use sed only using `!`. I tried to change sed to a vim command (`set makeprg=tidy\ -e\ --gnu-emacs\ yes\ \\\|\ '%s/\\r$//g'`) but with this command I don't have any output. (empty quickfix window). Same if I escape the pipe only 1 time.

Comment: @Remonn sed is an external command and the pipe is done in the shell. So I am not sure what your comment means unless you mean sed isn't in your path? No `!` is necessary since the whole command is supposed be executed outside vim. And pipeing to a vim command doesn't make sense (since youre in a shell)

Comment: When I use above sed command it gives this error: ` || sed: expression -e #1, character 1: unknown command: ``''`

Comment: @Remonn you're going to need to look up the syntax for your version of sed. I'm using GNU sed. I'm not sure what version of sed you are working with

Comment: FDinoff, I'm using GNU sed as well (and I added the sed path in the environment). Maybe sed gives problems with the other commands. Have you tried all commands together?

Comment: @Remonn I didn't try it with tidy. I don't have it installed. I tried it with `cat file | sed 's/\\r$//'` where the file was create with unix2dos so that it would have the windows line endings.

Comment: @Remonn maybe I made a stupid assumption. Does tidy put its output on stdout?

Comment: @Remonn I know what the problem was. I didn't realise you were passing the file name to make. You need to add `$*` to the makeprg to specify where the arguments go

Comment: FDinoff, Now it works as before but I still have the `^M` at the end of every line in quickfix window

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin. It supports `tidy` as one of the syntax checkers for HTML.